# Are there contemporary buildings that have been designed based on colour psychology?

Tags: color, environmental-psychology

I am writing my thesis on how environmental psychology has influenced architecture and i am focusing on colour. I am looking for buildings that have been designed based on how colour affects the human psychology and physiology.

Comment: Welcome. Your question is appreciated but it's really broad. One good way to bring focus to your post is to add your prior research so far. What sources have you tried? What have you found so far? Psychology and physiology are very broad terms. Can you narrow it down?

Answer (score 0):

Restaurants such as Mc Donalds and In N Out use the red/ yellow color scheme as it is proven to induce hunger. Subway stations were fitted with blue lights in an effort to reduce suicides occurring within them and for reasons still undecided- it worked. I learned this from my ap psychology class recently.

Comment: Welcome Karissa. Thanks for your answer here and elsewhere. We represent a scientific stack, as such we ask that answers are accompanied by relevant sources, preferably links to journal papers. I'll banner your answer for now,. It would be awesome if you could elaborate on your answer here and provide sources to allow other users to background read on the topic.

Comment: Looks like the blue light thing is a reference to Matsubayashi, T., Sawada, Y., & Ueda, M. (2013). Does the installation of blue lights on train platforms prevent suicide? The effect size there is a whopping 87%, so it might be that this study was a victim of winner's curse. Probably not deliberate author shenanigans, but  definitely a very high risk of failing to replicate given that there is no proposed mechanism. There are some more fleshed out skeptical grumblings from Ichikawa et al. 2014 if you like your science with some salt.

Comment: @steveLangsford: thanks, I never heard of that before. It looks like there's mass media coverage of it too http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20190122-can-blue-lights-prevent-suicide-at-train-stations

Comment: Please don't use the term 'proven' as applied to science, there is no such thing, maybe you are thinking of math or logic.  Read about color psychology here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_psychology.  This field of study is very young, and is rarely studied by scientists - most of the available evidence is from marketing and administrative fields, where standards of evidence are often lower.  I'd like to see a decent study on the red/yellow-appetite thing - I suspect that's an urban myth, and the blue light thing has an excessively large error-margin.  Certainly not 'proven'.